# Emacs: Using ffap and ido-mode together

Tags: emacs, ido

I used to work with `find-file-at-point` to open files, URLs etc. My `.emacs` contains

```
(require 'ffap)
(ffap-bindings)
```

I discovered `ido-mode` and I tried to use it with

```
(ido-mode 1); enable ido-mode
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t); flexibly match names
(setq ido-everywhere t); use ido-mode everywhere, in buffers and for finding files
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess); for find-file-at-point
```

It turns out that `C-x C-f` for finding a file does not activate `ido-mode` (I do not see the typical suggestions of file names as I do for buffers when doing `C-x b`). When I comment out the two lines related to `ffap`, it works as expected, however, I would like to use `ffap` as well.

Is this possible?

Assume the point is on an URL. It would be great if `C-x C-f C-f` (the fallback to the "old" completion style) would activate `ffap` and thus offer to open the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- you need to rebind the functions that you use.

You look inside ffap at the functions that you need , and rebind them like that:

(global-set-key [end] 'function)

(you change the end key with your combination).

There are many ways to rebind a key, but first of all start looking at the functions that are useful for you inside ffap.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I only needed `find-file-at-point` which used to be `C-x C-f`. I used `(setq ffap-require-prefix t)` to get it via `C-u C-x C-f` if required.